# Generic mapping of xml to java bean using JSXB

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb

I have map xml content to a java bean. I am using JAXB to convert it to my bean class.
This works fine. But for this I need to know the content of xml beforehand. If some new elements are added in xml I have to change the code.
I want to avoid this. How can I achieve this.

```
   <Mangos>
       <Mango name='mangoA' color='yellow' />
       <Mango name='mangoB' color='green' />
   </Mangos>
  <Bananas>
       <Banana name='bananaA' color='yellow' />
       <Banana name='bananaB' color='green' />
   </Bananas >
</Fruit >

@XmlRootElement(name = "Fruit")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Fruit {
   @XmlElementWrapper(name= "Mangos")
   @XmlElement(name = "Mango")
   private List<FruitPojo> mangos;

   @XmlElementWrapper(name= "Bananas")
   @XmlElement(name = "Banana")
   private List< FruitPojo > bananas;
}

public class FruitPojo {
   
   private String name;
   private String color;
}
```

Comment: Use a preprocessor.

Comment: what is a preprocessor, can you guide me to a link

Comment: Not sure, I just thought it sounded cool. Perhaps this helps [JAXB-2 Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/).